# PyTorch DataLoader Error: object of type 'type' has no len()

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader

I'm quite new to programming and have now clue where my error comes from.

I got the following code to set up my dataset for training my classifier:

```
class cows_train(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, folder_path):
        self.image_list = glob.glob(folder_path+'/content/cows/train')
        self.data_len = len(self.image_list)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        single_image_path = self.image_list[index]
        im_as_im = Image.open(single_image_path)
        im_as_np = np.asarray(im_as_im)/255
        im_as_np = np.expand_dims(im_as_np, 0)
        im_as_ten = torch.from_numpy(im_as_np).float()
        class_indicator_location = single_image_path.rfind('/content/cows/train/_annotations.csv')
        label = int(single_image_path[class_indicator_location+2:class_indicator_location+3])
        return (im_as_ten, label)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.data_len
```

And this for the DataLoader:

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

batch_size = 4

trainset = cows_train
trainloader =    torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = trainset, batch_size=10,

shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

classes = ('cow_left', 'cow_other')
```

As Output I receive:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-54702f98a725> in <module>()
      6 
      7 trainset = cows_train
----> 8 trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = trainset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
      9 
     10 testset = cows_test

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __init__(self, dataset, batch_size, shuffle, sampler, batch_sampler, num_workers, collate_fn, pin_memory, drop_last, timeout, worker_init_fn, multiprocessing_context, generator, prefetch_factor, persistent_workers)
    264                     # Cannot statically verify that dataset is Sized
    265                     # Somewhat related: see NOTE [ Lack of Default `__len__` in Python Abstract Base Classes ]
--> 266                     sampler = RandomSampler(dataset, generator=generator)  # type: ignore
    267                 else:
    268                     sampler = SequentialSampler(dataset)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py in __init__(self, data_source, replacement, num_samples, generator)
    100                              "since a random permute will be performed.")
    101 
--> 102         if not isinstance(self.num_samples, int) or self.num_samples <= 0:
    103             raise ValueError("num_samples should be a positive integer "
    104                              "value, but got num_samples={}".format(self.num_samples))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py in num_samples(self)
    108         # dataset size might change at runtime
    109         if self._num_samples is None:
--> 110             return len(self.data_source)
    111         return self._num_samples
    112 

TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

Problem is: I don't understand why typ has no length, in my eyes it's defined... Someone please help?

Add: This is where "return len(self.data_source)" shows up in the code

> ```
> def num_samples(self) -> int:
>     if self._num_samples is None:
>         return len(self.data_source)
>     return self._num_samples
> ```

Comment: You should post the code that causes the actual error or it will be very hard to debug. In this case, you need to post the code block that contains `return len(self.data_source)`

Comment: Might be this one: (?)
def num_samples(self) -> int:
      if self._num_samples is None:
            return len(self.data_source)
      return self._num_samples

Comment: Code didn't display. Please add to original question

Answer (score 2):

You are not creating your dataset object correctly. Currently, you do:

```
trainset = cows_train
```

This only assigns the class type to `trainset`. To create an object of the class, you need to use:

```
folder_path = '/path/to/dataset/'
trainset = cows_train(folder_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error before. Removing shuffle=True solved the error in my case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).